# Is there any way to make lightning bolts deal no damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a game that requires for a lightning bolt to be spawned above everyone's heads every 3 seconds (so that they can be tracked). However, if a player is standing directly below another player when the lightning strikes, the lightning deals damage to the player above. Is there any NBT tag I could use to negate lightning damage? If not, can you think of any other possible workarounds?

Answer (score 6):

When summoning a LightningBolt with `/summon`, NBT input is ignored, so there is no NBT data you can provide.

As an alternative, 1.9 introduces a new block called the [End Gateway](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Gateway_%28block%29), which produces beams of light similar to beacons. Unlike beacons, there is no need for a specific structure and the beam will go through all blocks (both upwards and downwards).

You could potentially setblock an end gateway at Y0 via `/execute` to produce the same sort of effect without damaging the player. The `Age` long tag for end gateways will create a magenta beam of light so long as the value is below 200, so you can use that to specify the duration the beam should last for.

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ 0 ~ minecraft:end_gateway 0 replace {Age:160l}
```

---

Note that end gateway blocks will not teleport entities if the `ExitPortal` compound is not defined, but its beam will still become yellow if an entity enters it while `Age` is 200 or higher. If you wanted yellow beams instead of magenta, you could create the end gateway as well as summon an entity that will despawn after a set amount of time.

For example, the following creates an end gateway with an AreaEffectCloud entity inside it that will despawn after 100 ticks (5 seconds):

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ 0 ~ minecraft:end_gateway 0 replace {Age:200l}
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /summon AreaEffectCloud ~ 0 ~ {Duration:100}
```

Answer (score -3):

Connect this to a three second clock attach it to a command block

/execute @a ~ ~3 ~ summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~

The command summons a lightning bolt a block above a players head

Comment: That is exactly the command that the OP cannot use.

Comment: @Skylinerw sorry i edited it a bit don't know if it helps

Answer (score -3):

/execute @e[type=!player,type=!item,type=!item_frame] ~ ~3 ~ summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~

Comment: Just like in the other down-voted answer, simply summoning a lightning bolt is not enough. Also you're *excluding* players, which is not asked.